# md-sidenav animation not working

Tags: angularjs

I am using `md-sidenav` for ui-router. I'm not able to add animation to `sidenav`. I want the page to slide from left.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-cloak>
  <md-sidenav md-component-id="left" class="md-sidenav-left">
  </md-sidenav>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.md-sidenav-left {
  top:75px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 7px 9px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.7), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding-top:20px;      
  transition: 1.5s;     
  width: 970px;
  z-index:99;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;

}
```

**JS:**

```
      $scope.$watch('isSidenavOpen', function(isSidenavOpen) {
        //$scope.$watch(function(){
          $scope.isSidenavOpen = true;
          return $mdSidenav('left').isOpen();
          }, function(isOpen){             
               if(!isOpen) {
                 $state.go('home')
               }
          });
```

Also, I am maintaining state through the pages. Greatly appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console ? The info provided is very low..

Comment: no errors.. I have added the css styling for md-sidenav-left..

Comment: Can you fork this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q9fb0ejw/ or create new one with your setup to demonstrate the issue ?

Comment: I am  maintaining states between pages.. I tried your example but for the second time when I click the state does not change to previous value..

Comment: Given the fiddle works, with your code in it, it's obviously something else. *I want the page to slide from left.* you mean the menu right ? Please describe/update the question with what it is that you are doing and what is expected. Are you trying to hide the navigation after the user has clicked on the link in the menu ?

Comment: Yes.. When we slide the menu over the page.. the state(url) changes.. and when its close, it should go back to previous state ie. url. I have added the JS in the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.html: missing `md-is-open` tag.

```
<md-sidenav md-component-id="left" md-is-open="isSidenavOpen" class="md-sidenav-left">
```

2.script: You are watching changes on `$scope.isSidenavOpen`, when triggered, it is set to `true` or `false` by `md-is-open`. You shouldn't need to update it to `true` again and leave it `true` which is why it was always open. This should suffice.

```
$scope.$watch('isSidenavOpen', function () {
    //..Anything you want with the $scope.isSidenavOpen
    if ($scope.isSidenavOpen) {
        console.log('A')
    } else {
        console.log('B')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're maintaining states, but here is an example with the ui-router.

Simply used the watch on `isSideNavOpen` & added an `if-else` condition to change states.

```
$scope.$watch('isSidenavOpen', function(isSidenavOpen) {
    if(isSidenavOpen){
        $state.go('about');
    }
    else{
        $state.go('home');
    }    
});
```

This plunk is created from @Searching 's fiddle and contains most of the code from your question.

[Plunk!](https://plnkr.co/edit/PB6ROk) (You have to launch the preview in a separate window to see it change states)

If this still doesn't solve the issue the best would be to fork this plunk and recreate your scenario there.